# Help Identifying Sun Cruiser Tandem Bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, cruiser

I was gifted this tandem bike and would love help identifying the brand, model, and year on this! Can anyone help?

Thanks so much!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m considering selling this and I don’t know what it’s worth, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Nice bike.  Do note that valuations are off topic so we won't be able to help with that.   A bike is worth whatever someone is prepared to pay for it.   Tandems are relatively uncommon, so you might prefer to keep it, for yourself or for family, rather than selling it.   Or gift it to someone who will use it.

Comment: Don't sell it, ride it :) Tandem riding is much more fun than people believe. Tandem bikes are not just a silly novelty item but can be used for all kinds of touring, some people even travel the world on one. Because of the improved strength-to-aerodynamics ratio, you can more easily do long and fast tours than on single bikes, especially if one rider is less experienced. They are also great for e.g. picking up friends at the railway station. They also never fail to attract looks! Kids also love tandems, if you have any in your family, they might love to ride the bike with you.

Answer (score 1):

There's been a bike company named Sun making tandems since before WW2.

- Brand: Sun
- Model: Cruiser tandem
- Year: Unknown - probably 1990-2010 range.

The bike looks nice and comfortable to ride, with wide plush tyres, and relatively high handlebars/low saddles it will give an upright ride.

That bike is not built for speed, but for getting out and around in pairs.

The V brakes front and rear, with no third brake suggest its not really for touring, and the timing chain on the right-side with one-piece bottom brackets shows its an entry level bike.

In the Trendy category, it could legitimately be called a 1by because its a single chainring and probably 7 speed derailleur at the rear.

---

All in all its a loverly bike and would be a pleasure to ride.  Especially in these days of pandemic.

It would also make an excellent platform for a cargo bike conversion, should that be more use to you.

As per Carel's comment, the two cranks are at different positions in their cycle.  A conventional tandem has both cranks in identical parts of their rotation, so that both riders are pressing the same side crank down at the same time.
This makes for a better "feeling" else one rider's cranks push themselves forward at the wrong part of the stroke, and also when cornering.  Though this bike probably doesn't corner aggressively, it is still possible to get pedal strike.
 To fix this, just unship one end of the sync chain, rotate a crank to match the other, and refit the chain.  There is a chain tensioner under the keel tube which will allow the slack needed for this simple tweak.

Comment: The nearest I could find was https://www.ebth.com/items/5413617-sun-cruiser-tandem-bicycle which doesn't give any more sub-model information or a year, but the frame's a dead-ringer for yours.

Comment: It might be kind of difficult to ride because the cranks are out of sync.The stoker will most likely hit the captain's heels and turns might cause at least one pedal strike.

Comment: @Carel excellent point, and something that wouldn't be immediately obvious even to a cyclist who has not ridden a tandem.

Answer (score 0):

I have sun beam tandem 7 speed  got mine brand new from a pawn shop in Longwood florida about 2007 I have a plate tha reads made in taiwan

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Does your bike look like the one pictured?  Do you have any information about when it was made?

Comment: Are you saying yours is the same as OPs ?  Sun Beam is different to Sun Cruiser.